# How to run an application in open shift without typing application name at the end of domain name?

Tags: java, openshift

I have created an application(opencart) in open shift. They have been provided a domain to run my application.

Example :- `opencart-opencart.rhc.com`.

By using this domain i can run my application only when adding my application name at the end of domain like `opencart-opencart.rhc.com/opencart`.

So, how to run without typing application name at the end of domain.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you edit your .htaccess file? Then check this: http://www.apache.com/www/how-to-redirect-pages-using-a-301-redirect-and-the-htaccess-file/

Comment: Ok,my problem has been solved.

Comment: How? Please provide your solution here,

Comment: i've just renamed my war file name as ROOT